# Air Pollution and High Pass engines

Tags: aircraft-performance

If Air is use. “High Bypass Turbines”.  Where does air pollution come in that is mentioned frequently by Politicians and media

I’m a total layman at this

Comment: Fuel is used to turn the fan which pushes air. What don't you understand?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Can you phrase your question in complete sentences? It's hard to understand what you want to know like this. Please have a look at the answers to [What is the difference between turbojet and turbofan engines?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/71301/what-is-the-difference-between-turbojet-and-turbofan-engines) and then edit your question to include what's still unclear to you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a jet engine burn fuel when it is not on an afterburner?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/89620/how-does-a-jet-engine-burn-fuel-when-it-is-not-on-an-afterburner)

Answer (score 1):

All turbine engines regardless of specific type burn hydrocarbon-based fuel (kerosene, basically) in order to generate propulsion. The burning of these fuels creates carbon dioxide as a byproduct, which is a pollutant.